# golang: How to manage packages in the local file-system

Tags: go, import, package

i am sure this has been asked many, many times: »How can i create and manage my go-packages locally without for example github ?«

I need to convert a couple of tools that were written in Perl to golang and i am fighting with golang's package management, simple example:

I wrote the main-package, containing the main function and a couple of other functions.
Now i want to move a group of functions into another package:

- Created another package in the same directory and moved the group of
  functions there
- Built the package and the binary-file was created
- Tried to import this package into the main package and miserably
  failed. "PackageName", "./PackageName" "[fullpath]/PackageName" all
  fails

For starters: How can i import a package from the local file-system?

Comment: Packages within your module are always imported from the local filesystem. Please go through the intro docs, like [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/) or the other official tutorials.

Comment: Have you done a `go mod init` and built a reasonable directory structure for your packages? This is really difficult to offer any suggestions on without seeing any code or anything. Relative import paths are definitely wrong, but other than that all we can do from the information given is guess and refer to the docs.

Comment: Hi Adrian, i have managed to create the following structure: My program is located in /home/fjuedes/golang/hello and a package lives in /home/fjuedes/golang/hello/morestrings. I can import the package into the my program using the name "home/fjuedes/golang/hello/mystrings" - without the leading slash! - It works but i don't understand why. I then have created a second package in home/fjuedes/golang/packages/morestrings2 - outside of the main-programs folder. I was able to build this package but unable to import the package into my test-program. Error: [package] not within GOROOT

Comment: i recommend using go.work, after creating the modules as stated by the comments above

Answer (score 0):

Run `go mod init <module_name>` in the dir where you want to store all your code.

Example: `go mod init auth-api`

This will create a `go.mod` file in your root folder.

You can create a separate folder for each package.

Your dir structure looks like this.

```
package_1
-- file_1_1.go
-- file_1_2.go
package_2
-- file_2_1.go
-- file_2_2.go
-- file_2_3.go

main.go
go.mod
```

Here `package_1` contains the `file_1_1.go` and `file_1_2.go`. Start these files with `package package_1`

Ex:

```
// file_1_1.go

package package_1
import "fmt"

func SayHelloFromPackage_1(){
   fmt.Println("Hello from Package 1")
}
```

Now you can use that function in `main.go`:

```
// main.go
import "auth-api/package_1" // auth-api is our module name (go mod init auth-api)

func main() {
    package_1.SayHelloFromPackage_1()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vishal! - That is exactly what i am doing for now. I need to migrate a tool-set that is written in Pearl into another language that does not need to install additional packages on the target systems. The Perl-code requires a couple of modules to be installed before it can run. In some environments the GCC compiler must not be installed due to security concerns, so i needed a language which generates executable files that contain everything. Also important is the ability to generate code for ARM64 as more and more servers are ARM based.

Comment: It’s no bother.